# org.openntf.domino.Session.getDatabase() not working in Hybrid Xpages App on IBM Bluemix

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud, hybrid

I am working on Xpages hybrid application, where the frontend(ui) is on bluemix xpages runtime and backend(database) is on our on-premise server. Configured the entire thing as per the documentation from bluemix.

Issue is, I am not able to access database using org.openntf.domino.Session in the frontend using the code shown below. It returns null.

```
Session session = Factory.getSession(SessionType.FULL_ACCESS);
Database database = session.getDatabase("servername", "dbpath");
```

Where as I am able to access the database using the lotus.domino.session as shown below.

```
lotus.domino.Session session = ContextInfo.getUserSession();
lotus.domino.Database database = session.getDatabase("servername", "dbpath");
```

Is there a way to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: How did you add the OpenNTF library to your project?

Comment: I added openntf domino api plugin to bluemix runtime through shared-plugins folder in the deployment directory